# How to make xmonad workspace name display the number of window?

Tags: haskell, xmonad

Good evening, sorry to bother you with basic question.

Recently, i moved to xmonad. I'm very new to haskell and tried to learn it little by little. I want to make workspace name in xmonad to display the number of open windows. I will give an example for better understanding.

I have 3 workspaces, let's say "ws1", "ws2", and "ws3". I hope i can make it like this.

```
| ws1 (n1) | ws2 (n2) | ws3 (n3) |
```

where ws is the name of workspace and n is the number of window in each workspace. When i have 3 windows opened in ws1, 2 windows opened in ws2, and 0 window opened in ws3, it will be like this.

```
| ws1 (3) | ws2 (2) | ws3 (0) |
```

I don't know how to configure it in xmonad. Some people at xmonad channel told me that actually I can display it using

```
map (\ws -> (w.tag ws ,length . w.integrate . w.stack $ ws) w.workspaces `fmap` withwindowset
```

but i don't know where should i put that code.

I'm sorry for my English. I appreciate any help if someone knows how to do it.
Thank you.

Comment: You would have to add it to your log hook. What do you currently have as your logHook in your config?